# setting the tags for my UI elements?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I understand each element that exists on the View/Window has a tag that uniquely identifies it from the other. My question is, I am assuming that these are set by default internally, since clearly the inspector does not provide a way to set a tag for these (or does it?). I would like to be able to set the tag manually as I create my User interface through the NIB files. Is there a way to do this or do I need to go behind the scenes and create the necessary code to be able to do it.

Thanks,

Parijat Kalia

Comment: you can use the property .tag on any of those objects to set it yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `Tag` box on the right just below the `Background` color, `Alpha`, and `Mode` in the `View` section.  That sets the `.tag` property of the selected object.

[image: Tag]

Comment: Tag is a number?? Is Apple *trying* to get us to introduce bugs in our programs?

Comment: Im sure you could override tag to be an NSObject if you want/need.

Comment: Not for my desired use of them, which is to declare a tag in interface builder and use that tag to look up the object from code (like an id in html/javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Setting tags:

```
UISlider *sliderRed = (UISlider *)[self.view viewWithTag:10];
UISlider *sliderGreen = (UISlider *)[self.view viewWithTag:11];
UISlider *sliderBlue = (UISlider *)[self.view viewWithTag:12];
```

Is this what you mean? yes it does provide a way.

Answer (score 0):

Tags are not set automatically.  You have to set them manually either in code (view.tag = someinteger) or using Interface Builder.  If you choose the Attributes inspector in Interface Builder, scroll down to the "View" section.  There's a box for the Tag value there.

Comment: jeez, I completely overlooked this part, thanks so much for your help :)